# Junit does not correctly compare objects?

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm using jUnit in Android Studio, and either I'm completely overlooking something, or jUnit is just not working right... I got this sample code:

```
ChatContent testContent = new ChatContent(new ArrayList<ChatMessage>());
ChatContent testContent2 = new ChatContent(new ArrayList<ChatMessage>());
assertThat(testContent, equalTo(testContent2));
```

And when I run the test, I get the error message

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected: [...].ChatContent@7fbe847c
>        but: was [...].ChatContent@41975e01
>   Expected :[...].ChatContent@7fbe847c
>
> Actual   :[...].ChatContent@41975e01

This should not happen, because equalTo() only tests for equality and not *true* equality like `==` does, right?

ChatContent is basically just a class which holds an instance of `List<ChatMessage>`, it doesn't do much else.

I currently use jUnit, Mockito and Hamcrest (all up-to-date) in my project.

Comment: Did you override `equals` in `ChatContent` ?

Comment: == compares references.  It'll always be false when you have two calls to new.

Comment: @duffymo It compares what the references "redidrect" to. @khelwood No, because it was not necessary. And I wouldn't consider it good practise to override `toString()`, `equals()` etc. in every class I create...

Comment: == compares the reference values, which are different in this case. If you have not overridden equals, it uses the superclass implementation. If it is Object, it just does the reference check. Which again would explain your problem.

Comment: Not a good practice to override equals and hashCode?  That was my point in asking about ==.  It sounds to me like you don't understand the difference between shallow and deep equals in Java.  That's exactly why you're having a problem.

Comment: @Namnodorel It's not just good practice, but *mandatory* to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in every class that you expect to be compared logically rather than by reference equality.

Comment: @duffymo No, I didn't mean that `==` and `equals()` are the same thing. I just wasn't aware that `equals()` by default just returns `(this == obj)`... Also, knowing that there are different types of comparison is one of the very basic things in Java, and if I wouldn't know that, how would I even get to things like unit testing? That assumption comes over as a little bit rude. When I think about it, I just never had the need to compare any objects that were inherited from the `object`base class... And that's why I didn't override `equals()` or thought that that would be a problem.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I would actually mark your comment as answer it it were possible...

Comment: Exactly - you weren't aware.  It's entirely possible to unit test and get the right behavior out of your scenario.  It sounds like you aren't doing it.

Comment: @duffymo But that wasn't what... Whatever, nothing productive can come outta this discussion anymore. The important thing is that I now know what was wrong.

Comment: This is Java 101.  That's a very productive lesson for you to learn.

Comment: @duffymo You know what i don't like? People talking to me like a child... Yes, I made a  mistake. But that mistake is not what you apparently think. With "discussion" I meant that I don't want to discuss with you why I think that you misinterpreted what I say... You seem to insist on me being unexperienced in Java and not knowing what the difference between different types of comparison is. Which is not true. But  I really, _really_ don't want to discuss this, because whatever the outcome is will not be relevant for both of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the Javadoc for the calls you are using, like here for [equalTo](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#equalTo(T)):

*Creates a matcher that matches when the examined object is logically equal to the specified operand, as determined by calling the Object.equals(java.lang.Object) method on the examined object.*

So, as to be expected: it is not JUnit or Hamcrest that is *incorrect*. What is *incorrect* are your *assumptions*. You assume that equalTo() would be the same as ==. And when your observations didn't match your expectations; you assumed that reality is broken, instead of questioning your own *assumptions*.

Hint: most of the times, it is the other way round.

In that sense, the answer is: override equals() and hashCode(). Or decide that you don't need a test like this. Both ways would work; it depends on your context which one fits you better.

Comment: All in all, the answer is correct. But just as I made a wrong assumption, you did as well... I just was not aware that `obj.equals(...)` by default uses `==` (Which then actually boils down to that `equalsTo()` IS the same thing as `==`... When `equals()` is not overriden. But that's also why I wrote "either I'm completely overlooking something". I know a so popular framework is probably not wrong, but I also was unable to detect my mistake.  Which is why I asked here, and didn't submit a bug report at jUnit. But admittedly, the title was easy to misunderstand.

Comment: Anyway... Glad we could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The Hamcrest equalTo method by default calls the Object.equals() method (ChatContent.equals() in your case)  I agree with khelwood that you would have to override .equals to get your desired behavior, but since you're using Hamcrest, I would suggest a CustomMatcher.

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/03/07/create-your-own-matcher/